# Passing parameter to Controller in View with MVC

Tags: html, post, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to pass a parameter to a controller from a button on a view.
I have tried many different ways but none are successful. I keep getting a non nullable error because the parameter is not getting passed, or so it seems. I have hard coded the parameter and still error out. I also have set parameter argument to optional in controller and it runs of course but shows no sign of passing the parameter as expected.

My simple button to pass parameter from view.
'''

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("ControllerMethod","DefaultController", new {id=Item.id })">Start</a>
```

'''
My controller
'''

```
Public ActionResult ControllerMethod (int ID){
// code
}
```

'''

Also: My route filter is unchange and default - unsure if I should have to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code (no worries). Just change it to this :

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("ControllerMethod","DefaultController", new { ID = Item.id })">Start</a>
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me an error: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: Oops my bad, I edited the answer, Change the quotes from ' ' to " "